# The entity type IdentityUser is not part of the model for the current context in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I want to check if there is a user with particular username and password in ASP.NET Identity. I tried and that is my code:

```
UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
var user = await userManager.FindAsync(userName, password);
```

However, something goes wrong and that is the error:

> The entity type IdentityUser is not part of the model for the current
>   context.

Would you tell me a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using default MVC project you have to use `ApplicationUser` model instead of  `IdentityUser` and update your code as follow:

```
  public async Task<ViewResult> Index()
    {
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var user = await userManager.FindAsync("UserName", "Password");
        return View(user);
    }
```

Comment: I worked but now I have another problem. The FindAsync function doesn't respond