# OwinContext. The entity type IdentityUser is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I got an error while doing a demo Web API using .NET Framework and trying to implement custom authentication using JWT and Identity Framework, everything was going smooth.

I already had a simple auth using Identity already working, but, when I implemented a relationship between **AspNetUsers** and my model **Person** I got an exception*'The entity type IdentityUser is not part of the model for the current context.'*

I think that it might as well be something related with OwinContext because while debugging everything works fine, it gets the user data from the table but when the next code is executed it just returns the exception(mentioned above).

Also I think it is different from other questions because OwinContext is the one that throws the exception when using the GetRoles method.

```
var userRoles = context.OwinContext.Get<TwitterUserManager>().GetRoles(user.Id.ToString());
```

My **DB Context**:

```
public class FakeTwitterContext: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{

    public FakeTwitterContext() : base("FakeTwitterConnection")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

}
```

My **ApplicationUser**:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //. . .

    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser(): base()
    {

    }
}
```

My **PersonEntityConfig**:

```
public class PersonConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    public PersonConfiguration()
    {
        //. . .

        HasRequired(p => p.ApplicationUser)
            .WithRequiredDependent(appUser => appUser.Person)
            .Map(p => p.MapKey("UserId"));
    }
}
```

And my **CustomOAuthProvider.cs** (where the code crashes)

```
public class CustomOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        var user = context.OwinContext.Get<FakeTwitterContext>()
            .Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == context.UserName);

        if (!context.OwinContext.Get<TwitterUserManager>()
            .CheckPassword(user, context.Password)
            )
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect");
            context.Rejected();
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(SetClaimsIdentity(context, user), new AuthenticationProperties());
        context.Validated(ticket);

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    private static ClaimsIdentity SetClaimsIdentity(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context, ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("JWT");
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));

        //Error
        //The entity type IdentityUser is not part of the model for the current context.
        var userRoles = context.OwinContext.Get<TwitterUserManager>().GetRoles(user.Id.ToString());
        foreach (var role in userRoles)
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }

        return identity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The entity type IdentityUser is not part of the model for the current context in ASP.NET Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40249076/the-entity-type-identityuser-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-current-context-in)

Comment: Not possible, my error is in OwinContext, I'm not using MVC it is just a web API that tries to implement authentication, I had already checked that answer. 
Thanks anyways.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?